# Consuming a WCF service in netbeans java application

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, netbeans

[see exception image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVCTr.png)

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.Options$Target
    at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.Options.<init>(Options.java:174)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportOptions.<init>(WsimportOptions.java:84)
    at org.netbeans.modules.websvc.api.jaxws.wsdlmodel.WsdlModeler.generateWsdlModel(WsdlModeler.java:172)
    at org.netbeans.modules.websvc.api.jaxws.wsdlmodel.WsdlModeler.generateWsdlModel(WsdlModeler.java:168)
    at org.netbeans.modules.websvc.api.jaxws.wsdlmodel.WsdlModeler.access$000(WsdlModeler.java:53)
    at org.netbeans.modules.websvc.api.jaxws.wsdlmodel.WsdlModeler$1.run(WsdlModeler.java:78)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1418)
    at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.GlobalLookup.execute(GlobalLookup.java:45)
    at org.openide.util.lookup.Lookups.executeWith(Lookups.java:278)
[catch] at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2033)
```

I am trying to create a `java` application in order to consume a `WCF` service. While creating this web service client, I got this exception and I can not see the web service components in the tree view in `netbeans`.

Answer (score 0):

did you found a solution ? It looks it is a Netbeans bug. I tried to add the JAX-WS library in the ejb module as it contains the missing class, but it is not available to the IDE of course.
In fact this is an error catched by the IDE log:

SEVERE [org.openide.util.RequestProcessor]: Error in RequestProcessor org.netbeans.modules.websvc.api.jaxws.wsdlmodel.WsdlModeler$1
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.Options$Target
at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.Options.(Options.java:174)
at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportOptions.(WsimportOptions.java:84)
at org.netbeans.modules.websvc.api.jaxws.wsdlmodel.WsdlModeler.generateWsdlModel(WsdlModeler.java:172)
at org.netbeans.modules.websvc.api.jaxws.wsdlmodel.WsdlModeler.generateWsdlModel(WsdlModeler.java:168)
at org.netbeans.modules.websvc.api.jaxws.wsdlmodel.WsdlModeler.access$000(WsdlModeler.java:53)
at org.netbeans.modules.websvc.api.jaxws.wsdlmodel.WsdlModeler$1.run(WsdlModeler.java:78)
at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1418)
at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.GlobalLookup.execute(GlobalLookup.java:45)
at org.openide.util.lookup.Lookups.executeWith(Lookups.java:278)
[catch] at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2033)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31086842)